# Create accessible checkbox group with multiple descriptions

Tags: forms, accessibility

I want to create an checkbox group like so:
[image]

How do I make sure this is set up in the right way for it to be fully accessible?

I have something like this at the moment:

```
<div role="group" aria-labelledby="group_head" aria-describedby="group__description">
  <h1 id="group_head">Heading 1</h1>
  <div class="group__description">Descriptive text about this checkbox group</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" id="checkbox_1" aria-describedby="description_1">
      <label for="checkbox_1">Checkbox 1</label>
      <p id="description_1">This is the descriptive text explaining the checkbox 1</p>
    </li>
        <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_2" id="checkbox_1" aria-describedby="description_2">
      <label for="checkbox_1">Checkbox 2</label>
      <p id="description_2">This is the descriptive text explaining the checkbox 2</p>
    </li>
        <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" id="checkbox_3" aria-describedby="description_3">
      <label for="checkbox_1">Checkbox 3</label>
      <p id="description_1">This is the descriptive text explaining the checkbox 3</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/studiovds/to2ka3v7/)

Comment: This already looks pretty good. What makes you ask for more?
One thing that might be improved is the first rule of ARIA: Use HTML instead, in this case the `<fieldset>` element along with a `<legend>` could do the grouping for you.

Comment: Users navigate forms principally by means of tab, in which case your group_head would be read, but afaik not the group__description. You could work around that by adding the latter to your `aria-labelledby`, or better, include both in the `<legend>`.

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/studiovds/to2ka3v7/10/

Comment: @Andy on adding both the label and description to the legend: would that not fail to respect users' verbosity settings? AFAICR what gets announced when tabbing to a control depends on that. Combining everything in the control's label can create pretty long accessible names and might bother returning users.

Comment: I’m not suggesting adding the description to the control’s label, but to the group. Yes, it will ignore the verbosity settings, but if its important it should be in the name, and it will only be announced once when entering the group. I tried to clarify that in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That already looks pretty good. Grouping has the advantage that it’s accessible name only gets announced once when the user enters the group.

It’s description (`aria-describedby`) is not part of the accessible name, so it won’t get announced by screen readers when the user navigates to the first checkbox (by means of tab).

If the group’s description is an indication important to the user’s choice, it shouldn’t be an optionally read description, but in the name. My suggestion would then be to group both texts together in a semantically correct `<fieldset>` and `<legend>`.

This will no longer respect the users verbosity setting and simply always announce that indication once the group is entered.

Alternatively, you might want to add the description’s ID to the group’s Labels: `<div role="group" aria-labelledby="group_head group__description">`.

```html
<fieldset>
<legend>
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <p>Descriptive text about this checkbox group</p>
</legend>
<ul>
  <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" id="checkbox_1" aria-describedby="description_1">
      <label for="checkbox_1">Checkbox 1</label>
      <p id="description_1">This is the descriptive text explaining the checkbox 1</p>
  </li>
  <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_2" id="checkbox_2" aria-describedby="description_2">
      <label for="checkbox_2">Checkbox 2</label>
      <p id="description_2">This is the descriptive text explaining the checkbox 2</p>
  </li>
  <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" id="checkbox_3" aria-describedby="description_3">
      <label for="checkbox_3">Checkbox 3</label>
      <p id="description_1">This is the descriptive text explaining the checkbox 3</p>
  </li>
</ul>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: "It’s description (aria-describedby) is not part of the accessible name, so it won’t get announced by screen readers when the user navigates to the first checkbox (by means of tab)": on which SR/browser combinations please? Can you cite a source?

Comment: Hi @RobinMétral. For the first part,  that’s in the standard: https://w3c.github.io/aria/#namecomputation. The description has nothing to do with the name. For the second part, it was more of a logical conclusion that screen readers only announce the accessible name of a grouping when it’s entered. I can confirm that with NVDA+Firefox. The focused child’s description will be announced, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the details! I meant a source about the description not being announced when tabbing to the control. a11ysupport.io seems to show that the description is spoken on all major SR/browser combinations: https://a11ysupport.io/tests/tech__aria__aria-describedby#assertion-aria-aria-describedby_attribute-contribute_to_description-html-input(type-text)_element (confirmed on macOS+Safari just now. It announces "[name][role][description]" with a short pause between the role and description)

Comment: These tests are done for the description of the control itself, not for the description of its group. I couldn’t find any specs or tests on the announcement of froups/regions…

Comment: So, I created another question finally, because I’m really wondering about the group thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74730865/when-and-based-on-which-specification-do-screen-readers-announce-a-group-name

Comment: Thanks, I'll watch your question :) maybe I can look into adding this case to allysupport.io as well