# When and based on which specification do screen readers announce a group name

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

The ARIA standard offers the `group` and the `region` roles to group contents or user interface objects.

Both require a name provided by author, and screen readers seem to announce when such a grouping is entered or left, announcing the grouping‘s name on enter. This also applies for other roles such as `list` or `dialog`.

I tried to pin that behaviour to some abstract role, but couldn’t identify a commonality between these roles in the [role hierarchy](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/1.2/class-diagram/).

I’m under the impression that TalkBack, Orca, NVDA and JAWS all have this behaviour, which is really practical.

**But based on which standard did they implement this, and what is the actual support status?** Can we rely on this for interface design?

ChromeVox, who is gaining in popularity, did not show this behaviour when I tested, but then again it has other big shortcomings as of now.

```html
<hgroup>
  <h2>Grouping examples</h2>
  <p>Entering/leaving each of these grouping might get announced by the screen reader, along with the grouping’s accessible name</p>
</hgroup>

<p><a href="#">Start here</a></p>

<hr>

<div role="group" aria-label="A div with role group">
  <button>Button inside group</button>
</div>

<hr>

<div role="radiogroup" aria-label="A div with role radiogroup">
  <label><input type="radio" name="radio1">Video</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radio1">killed</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radio1">the</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radio1">radio</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radio1">star</label>
</div>

<hr>

<ul aria-label="An unordered list">
  <li><button>Button in list</button></li>
  <li>and</li>
  <li>some</li>
  <li>items</li>
</ul>

<hr>

<div role="dialog" aria-label="A div with role dialog">
  <button>Button in a dialog</button>
</div>
```

Comment: NVDA with Firefox announces the name of each of these groupings when focus changes between them, even for list.

Comment: as far as I understand it, the HTML/ARIA is used to build an Accessibility Tree using the underlying OS's accessibility API, which is then exposed to assistive technologies - but as far as I know there's no specification for what assistive technologies should *do* with that information, and of course each one will make its own decisions.

Comment: I [suggested the test case at a11ysupport.io](https://github.com/accessibilitysupported/a11ysupport.io/issues/256)

Comment: So, Michael Fairchild pointed me to the expectation that screen readers should convey _boundaries_. A [search on the repository for boundaries](https://github.com/accessibilitysupported/a11ysupport.io/search?q=boundaries) delivers all test cases with that expectation.